# export bash variable on disk

Tags: bash, shell

I have this code to export bash variable on disk:

```
export_to_disk() {
    ### Export variable to disk for later reload
    eval "echo export $1=\"\$$1\"" > $2
    #source $2
}
export_to_disk $mvar file.sh
```

but, the exported variable is truncated.
How to fix it ?

Comment: What exactly do you expect in `file.sh` when `$mvar` has the content `1234567890`?

Comment: Do not use `eval` for this. It's completely unnecessary -- both bash and zsh (and they're two different shells -- use one tag or the other, not both at the same time) support indirect assignment without it. The `eval` practice here is for baseline POSIX shells, not for anything more capable.

Comment: Use indirect variable reference: `${!1}`

Comment: `export_to_disk() { varname=$1; shift; printf 'export %q=%q\n' "$varname" "${!varname}" >"$file"`

Comment: Please post a [mre] that shows how you're setting `mvar`.

Comment: Or even better, `declare -p "$1" >"$2"`. That's a _little_ different because it preserves exported-vs-unexported status whereas your current code will make an unexported variable become exported when it's imported, but that's an improvement: it's storing the value with greater fidelity.

Comment: The title said bash instead of zsh, so I took that to be the accurate way to resolve the conflict between title and tags. If your question is _really_ about zsh, take the bash tag out and change both the tag _and the title_ to reflect only zsh.

Comment: BTW, it'd be a better choice of calling convention to put the filename as the _first_ argument, and then treat all subsequent arguments as the names of variables to store in the file -- that way you can pass as many variable names as you want to just one call of the function.

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that `declare -p mvar >file.sh` is so simple you don't need a function to wrap it in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

`eval` is an [unnecessary source of security risks](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), and forcing `export` means your code isn't correctly preserving the original flags of the variable (which may or may not in fact be exported).

Let the shell itself be responsible for serializing the variable in a manner in which that same shell will be able to successfully deserialize it:

```
export_to_disk() {
  declare -p "$1" >"$2"
}

export_to_disk mvar file.sh  # notice mvar not $mvar
```

...but a smarter calling convention would be to put the file name as the *first* argument, so all following arguments are treated as variables to serialize into that file:

```
export_to_disk() {
  local export_to_disk__filename=$1; shift || return
  declare -p "$@" >"$export_to_disk__filename"
}

export_to_disk file.sh mvar anothervar thirdvar
```

---

That said, if you really do want to support only string-type variables that can be exported (losing support for arrays &c), you can do this without `declare -p`:

```
export_to_disk() {
  local export_to_disk__filename=$1; shift || return
  local export_to_disk__varname
  for export_to_disk__varname in "$@"; do
    printf '%s=%q\n; export %q\n' "$export_to_disk__varname" "${!export_to_disk__varname}" "$export_to_disk__varname"
  done
}
```

Let's break this down:

- In both this example and the earlier one, a long variable name that starts with `export_to_disk__` is used to prevent conflicts: If we called it something simple like `var`, then this program couldn't be used to save a variable named `var`. Using our own namespace for our variables makes the function wordier, but also makes it more powerful.
- Because we declare our local variables, variables we define for our own usage don't leak into the surrounding scope after we were called.
- Because we use `shift` after assigning the first argument to a variable, it's taken off the argument list and so is no longer in `"$@"` when we iterate over remaining arguments later.
- When we use `printf %q`, we're generating an *evaluation-safe* version of our variable's value, preventing security problems even with deliberately hostile or dangerous variable names. (Because we use `printf %s` for the variable *name*, things that aren't really valid variable names can cause this to generate unsafe code; so if you're sourcing code this command ran, you should be sure you trust the names, even if you don't trust the values).